# Installing python packages version by date of release

Tags: python, docker, pip, package

I have a list of python packages in my Docker file I want to install on the container, but I would like to install through `pip install`  all these packages as of the latest version released before a specific date. This because I suspect that my docker container started to crash after I updated some packages in it and the only thing I know is the last date it worked well. I would like to compose again the container with all the package versions I had at that time. Is there any way to do that? Is there a command I can insert in my docker file to obtain that?

Comment: Do you have a `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile.lock` file, checked into source control, that lists the exact package versions you're installing?  (In which case you can rewind that specific file to the last-known-working version, and rebuild the image.)

Answer (score 0):

use pip install requirements.txt

Syntax:

```
package_name==version

== equal to given version
>= greater or equal to version
>= less or equal to version
> greater than version 
> less than version
```

example of requirements.txt

> ordereddict==1.1
>
> argparse==1.2.1
>
> python-dateutil==2.2
>
> matplotlib==1.3.1
>
> nose==1.3.0
>
> numpy==1.8.0
>
> pymongo==3.3.0
>
> psutil>=2.0

install using this command

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

Comment: I know that, but I suppose there is no automatic way to know the latest package version released at a specified date. This can't be solved just by using a requirement.txt, because you don't really know the correct version to install.